# J2EE multi tenant SaaS application

Tags: jakarta-ee, multi-tenant, saas

I have to develop a multi tenant SaaS application in j2ee with implementing the three cloud models starting from the Iaas and PaaS,i chose openstack with openshift origin.
the first criteria for a SaaS application is multi-tenancy ,i know that there are 3 approaches to achieve it
 - Separate Databases
 - Shared Database, Separate Schemas
 - Shared Database, Shared Schema
i get lost here because many frameworks like ATHENA, ORM like hibernate and there is also TOPLINK.I need help to know the best approach to implement a multi tenant java application.

Answer (score 1):

I like the shared database shared schema approach - which in broad terms means every table has an org_id column and every query is run with the current user org_id as filter.

I like that way because you can shard the database balancing huge tenants with smaller tenants instead of having a custom scale according to each tenant size

I would skip altogether an ORM, too easy to mess things up in a multitenant deployment, and go with an [MyBatis](http://blog.mybatis.org/) solution which allow queries to be verified and reviewed as they are all centralized in few places instead of all over the code.

if you really need a ORM, I know Hibernate comes with [its own support](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html) but I don't like when libraries force me on a specific data structure, as it takes away flexibility. Just make sure that the only way to obtain a session automatically add tenancy, too easy to mess things up for devs if that is a manual process.

you can find lot of resource and some cost benefit analysis of different approaches here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx

Comment: "Just make sure that the only way to obtain a session automatically add tenancy, too easy to mess things up for devs if that is a manual process." -- Could you please elaborate

Comment: Usually devs go to an EntityManager (JPA) or a SessionFactory (Hibernate) or a SqlSessionFactoryBuilder (MyBatis) or what have you. Then they get a statement and if they go that route, they have to add to all statements 'AND TENANT=:tenantid' and they have to get the tenant from session and pass it. Too much point of failure: wrap that into an object that allow to create only statement/query/object which have the tenant clause forcibly injected, to free devs to have to remember that up.